# How to display option menu in android in Android API 17?

Tags: android

I am trying to display option menu. I am creating menu at run time using menu.add() method. I am using android API 17. IS there any menu button we have to click? I am having "menuItemsMap " as Map<> instance variable and i m adding menu into that map so that i can reuse these menu.
Thanks in Advance.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menuItemsMap = new HashMap<Integer, MenuItem>();
        menuItemsMap.put(
                R.string.pizzasCart_pizzasList,
                menu.add(R.string.pizzasCart_pizzasList).setIcon(
                        R.drawable.script_edit));
        menuItemsMap.put(
                R.string.pizzasList_viewShoppingCart,
                menu.add(R.string.pizzasList_viewShoppingCart).setIcon(
                        R.drawable.cart));
        menuItemsMap.put(
                R.string.pizzasCart_checkout,
                menu.add(R.string.pizzasCart_checkout).setIcon(
                        R.drawable.cart_go));
        menuItemsMap.put(
                R.string.pizzasList_viewUserData,
                menu.add(R.string.pizzasList_viewUserData).setIcon(
                        R.drawable.user_green));
        /*menu.add(1,1,0,R.string.pizzasCart_pizzasList).setIcon(R.drawable.script_edit);
        menu.add(1,2,1,R.string.pizzasList_viewShoppingCart).setIcon(R.drawable.cart);
        menu.add(1,3,2,R.string.pizzasList_viewUserData).setIcon(R.drawable.user_green);*/      
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        setMenuItemState(R.string.pizzasCart_pizzasList, false, false);
        setMenuItemState(R.string.pizzasList_viewShoppingCart, true,
                !isShoppingCartEmpty());
        setMenuItemState(R.string.pizzasCart_checkout, true,
                isShoppingCartCheckoutAllowed());
        setMenuItemState(R.string.pizzasList_viewUserData, true, true);

        return true;
    }

    protected void setMenuItemState(int itemTitleResID, boolean visible, boolean enabled) {
        MenuItem item = menuItemsMap.get(itemTitleResID);
        item.setEnabled(enabled);
        item.setVisible(visible);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getTitle().equals(getString(R.string.pizzasList_viewUserData))) {
            showUserDataActivity();

        } else if (item.getTitle().equals(
                getString(R.string.pizzasCart_pizzasList))) {
            showPizzasListActivity();

        } else if (item.getTitle().equals(
                getString(R.string.pizzasList_viewShoppingCart))) {
            showPizzasCartListActivity();

        } else if (item.getTitle().equals(
                getString(R.string.pizzasCart_checkout))) {
            checkoutShoppingCartPromptUser();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the menu button is the three dots on the top right of the action bar #4[image]

read up on menus http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: Action bar is not display on emulator?

Comment: yes it does, if it does not then you changed something in the manifest for it to not display

Comment: If I have to show menu at bottom of page then what setting i need to implement?